# Using BIOS int 13h to access sectors in different heads

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16, bootloader, osdev

I have a disk with 63 sectors per track. (I assume, based on my observations)
I want to read sectors on a 16 bit bootloader using int 13h.
For example, if I want to read sector number 63, I would do the following:

```
mov dl,0x80;Drive number
mov dh,0 ;This is head number/platter number
mov ch,0  ;This is cylinder number
mov cl,63 ;Sector number
mov ah,0x02 ;interrupt function
mov al,1  ;Number of sectors to be read
xor bx,bx 
mov es,bx ;Making es=0
mov bx,0x8000 ;Any random buffer address
int 0x13
```

The above code works as expected.

Now I want to read sector 64. I believe that it would be cylinder 0, head 1, sector 1.
I use:

```
mov dl,0x80;Drive number
mov dh,1 ;This is head number/platter number
mov ch,0  ;This is cylinder number
mov cl,1 ;Sector number
mov ah,0x02 ;interrupt function
mov al,1  ;Number of sectors to be read
xor bx,bx 
mov es,bx ;Making es=0
mov bx,0x8000 ;Any random buffer address
int 0x13
```

This doesn't work.

P.S. The reason I believe that the number of sectors per track is 63 is because simply setting cl = 64 also does not work

Comment: @MichaelPetch In my machine, I perform int 0x13/ah=8 and get a value of 0x4f24 in cx

Comment: @MichaelPetch That makes it clear! I should hopefully get the right result now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204570/discussion-between-suraaj-k-s-and-michael-petch).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**TL;DR**: The size of a drive (or drive image in emulators or virtual machines) may impact the number of heads, cylinders and sectors per track (SPT) reported by the BIOS. The values you may get by querying the BIOS may differ depending on the size and may vary from computer to computer and the [CHS translation scheme](http://www.uruk.org/orig-grub/PC_partitioning.txt) being used by the BIOS.

If you have a BIOS that reports a drive as having 16 heads and 63 SPT then a CHS(0, 1, 1) should be the 64th sector on the drive. If however the BIOS reports 16 heads and 36 SPT then the 64th sector is CHS(0, 1, 28). If using a hard drive with CHS addressing always query the BIOS for the number of heads and SPT and compute logical block addresses (LBA) when your bootloader runs. It is highly recommended to not hard code the number of cylinders, number of heads, and SPT value into a bootloader.

Rather than use 0x80 for a drive number, use the value in *DL* that the BIOS passes to your bootloader. Use that value rather than hard coding the boot drive number. I have some [General Bootloader Tips](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32705076/3857942) that covers that and other things you may wish to consider in doing legacy bootloader development.

---

Cylinder, Head, Sector (CHS) addressing came about from media that used magnetic media on round platters (or floppy disk). Wikipedia has a good [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylinder-head-sector) on the subject of CHS. A diagram depicting CHS in a physical sense:

[image]

[Image source Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylinder-head-sector#/media/File:Hard_drive_geometry_-_English_-_2019-05-30.svg)

---

A track is a concentric circle (on a single side of a platter) that is divided into sections called a sector. A drive head reads the tracks on one side of a platter. 2 heads are required to access both sides of a physical platter. A cylinder is the collection of all the tracks on the media as they appear one on top of another.

After time the concept of cylinders, sectors, and heads no longer matched the physical implementation however CHS addressing was still used to access data on a device for compatibility. [Logical Block Addressing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_block_addressing) (LBA) eventually obsoleted CHS and is the preferred method on media that appears as a hard drive to the BIOS. CHS addressing is still used on devices that present themselves as floppy disk media to the BIOS. LBA access to floppy media is not supported by all BIOSes, and CHS addressing is still the preferred mechanism in that case.

---

Your previous question and comments are intent on using CHS addressing on a hard drive. As I previously mentioned it is preferred with hard drives to use [Int 13h/AH=42H](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0708.htm) to avoid using CHS at all and using LBA instead. A logical block address starts at 0 and goes up to the total sector count on the drive minus 1. Dealing with an LBA is much easier.

The disadvantages of using BIOS functions that rely on CHS are that sectors are fixed to 512 bytes. With [LBA assist BIOS translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_block_addressing#LBA-assisted_translation) (Supported by BOCHS and QEMU) the maximum number of sectors you can read from a drive is 1024*255*63=16450560 sectors or 16450560*512=‭8422686720‬ (~7.844GiB/~8.423GB). You won't be able to read beyond that with CHS addressing.

You can convert an LBA using a formula I have previously described in a [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45495410/3857942):

> ```
> LBA is the logical block address
> HPC is the maximum number of heads per cylinder (reported by 
>     disk drive, typically 16 for 28-bit LBA)
> SPT is the maximum number of sectors per track (reported by
>     disk drive, typically 63 for 28-bit LBA)
>
> LBA addresses can be mapped to CHS tuples with the following formula 
>     ("mod" is the modulo operation, i.e. the remainder, and "÷" is 
>     integer division, i.e. the quotient of the division where any 
>     fractional part is discarded):
>
> C = (LBA ÷ SPT) ÷ HPC
> H = (LBA ÷ SPT) mod HPC
> S = (LBA mod SPT) + 1
>
> where C, H and S are the cylinder number, the head number, and the sector number
> ```

You can do the calculation in the reverse direction (CHS to LBA) using:

> ```
> CHS tuples can be mapped to LBA address with the following formula:
>
> LBA = (C × HPC + H) × SPT + (S - 1)
> ```

In order to compute CHS for a given LBA on the disk you need to know the Sectors Per Track (SPT) and the number of heads. [Int 13h/AH=8h](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0621.htm) can be used to retrieve  these values from the BIOS at runtime in the bootloader. In a [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47127909/3857942) I provide example code that uses [Int 13h/AH=8h](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0621.htm) to get SPT and Heads and computes CHS from a 32-bit LBA and then use those values to read a sector with [Int 13h/AH=2h](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0607.htm)

---

### LBA to CHS converter

The following *C* program takes 3 arguments. HEADS, SPT, and LBA to compute CHS using the formula above:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unsigned int heads;
    unsigned int spt; /* sectors per track */

    unsigned int h;  /* Head */
    unsigned int c;  /* Cylinder */
    unsigned int s;  /* Sector */

    unsigned int lba;

    if (argc != 4) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Usage: HEADS SPT LBA\n");
        return 1;
    }

    heads = atoi(argv[1]);
    if (heads > 255 || heads < 1) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Error: HEADS must be <= 255 and >= 1\n");
        return 1;
    }

    spt = atoi(argv[2]);
    if (spt > 63 || spt < 1) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Error: SPT must be <= 63 and >= 1\n");
        return 1;
    }

    lba = atoi(argv[3]);

    /* Proper calculation */
    c = (lba / spt) / heads;
    h = (lba / spt) % heads;
    s = (lba % spt) + 1;

    printf ("SPT = %u, Heads = %u\n", spt, heads);
    printf ("LBA = %u is CHS = (%u, %u, %u)\n\n", lba, c, h, s);
    if (c >= 1024)
        printf ("Can't use CHS because %u cylinders >= 1024, use LBA!\n", c);
    else
        printf ("DH = 0x%02X, CH = 0x%02X, CL = 0x%02X\n",
                h, c & 0xff, s | ((c >> 2) & 0xc0));

    return 0;
}
```

This program can be convenient if you want to compute CHS from an LBA. In your case you want to know the CHS values for the 64th sector on the disk. LBA's are 0 based so that is LBA 64-1=63. In your comments/chat the BIOS is reporting SPT=36 and Heads=16. If you compile and run the program above with:

```
gcc lbatochs.c -o lbatochs
./lbatochs 16 36 63
```

The result should be:

> ```
> SPT = 36, Heads = 16
> LBA = 63 is CHS = (0, 1, 28)
>
> DH = 0x01, CH = 0x00, CL = 0x1C
> ```

For a drive that the BIOS reports with SPT 63 and 16 heads the results should look like this for LBA 63:

```
./lbatochs 16 63 63
```

> ```
> SPT = 63, Heads = 16
> LBA = 63 is CHS = (0, 1, 1)
>
> DH = 0x01, CH = 0x00, CL = 0x01
> ```

Comment: I used int 13h /ah=8 on device 80h (hard disk 0). I got the following values: ax =0; bx =0; cx =003Fh ; dx = 0F01h

Comment: What is meant by ch being equal to 00?

Comment: @SuraajKS : It means the highest cylinder number on the drive is 0. Is your disk image less than ‭516096‬ bytes? What is the size of the disk image file you are using? In essence it means your disk has 1 cylinder.

Comment: Thus, if I wanted to access lba 63( in my above case) I would put dh=1,cl=1,ch=0

Comment: @SuraajKS That is why. A maximum cylinder of 0 means the drive has 0+1=1 total cylinders on it. I know the disk image had to be less than 516096 bytes since the heads=16 and SPT=63. 1 cylinder*16 heads*63 SPT*512=516096 bytes.

Comment: @SuraajKS Yes with Heads=16 and SPT=63, LBA 63 is CHS = (0, 1, 1). So you'd use DH=1, CL=1, CH=0

Comment: I have another query. Suppose I wanted to read lba = 62 (head 0) and lba = 63 (head 1), do I have to use int 13h twice (because the sectors aren't continous on a single track?)

Comment: @SuraajKS :To be most compatible never read  a number of sectors that cross a track boundary. Some BIOSes (most modern ones) do allow you to cross a track boundary (AKA multitrack reads) but you must never cross a cylinder boundary. If you read 1 sector at a time then you never have to worry about these problems.