# Linking first and second stage bootloader

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16, bootloader, stage

I am writing a two stage bootloader
Here is my boot.asm

```
[org 0x7c00]
[bits 16]
xor ax, ax
mov ds, ax
mov es, ax
xor bx, bx
mov ah, 0x0E
mov al, 'A'
int 0x10
jmp 0x8000
cli
hlt
times 510 - ($-$$) db 0
dw 0xAA55
```

And boot2.asm

```
[org 0x8000]
[bits 16]
xor ax, ax
mov ds, ax
mov es, ax
xor bx, bx
mov ah, 0x0E
mov al, 'B'
int 0x10
```

I compile it using

```
nasm -f bin -o boot.bin boot.asm
nasm -f bin -o boot2.bin boot2.asm
```

It compiles without any error or warning.
But how will I put stage 2 at 0x8000 and link stage1 and stage2 to work together?

Comment: According to your code stage2 is as 0x7e00 not 0x8000. Your first stage has to read the second stage into memory using something like [Int 13/ah=2](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0607.htm)

Comment: Its OK but how will I link both of them

Comment: This is  an example of a first stage reading a second stage and using NASM to generate a 1.44MB disk image: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54894586/3857942

Comment: Are you doing development on Windows? Linux? MacOS?

Comment: Oh I am developing on android phone!!!                 You must be surprised but its true, im a using termux terminal emulator for android.

Answer (score 2):

Likely you are asking how to combine the first and second stage into one file. If so:
*On*
**Linux:**

```
cat boot.bin boot2.bin > final_file.file_format
```

*On*
**Windows:**

```
copy /b boot.bin+boot2.bin  final_file.file_format
```

To load the second stage from the bootloader you can use the following code:

```
mov ah, 0x02      ; Read disk BIOS call 
mov cl, 0x02      ; sector to start reading from
mov al, 1         ; number of sectors that will be read (modify if your second stage grows)
mov ch, 0x00      ; cylinder number
mov dh, 0x00      ; head number
xor bx, bx
mov es, bx        ; ES=0x0000
mov bx, 0x8000    ; ES:BX(0x0000:0x8000) forms complete address to read sectors to
; DL should contain the boot disk number passed to the bootloader by the BIOS
int 0x13          ; Make BIOS disk services call (Int 0x13/AH=2) to read sectors
; For simplicity assume the disk read was successful
jmp 0x0000:0x8000 ; FAR JMP to second stage and ensure CS=0x0000
                  ; since CS is not guaranteed to be 0x0000 when control is transferred
                  ; to our bootloader
```

Answer (score 1):

> But how will I put stage 2 at 0x8000 ...

Unfortunately, I don't use "nasm" but other assemblers. But I'd expect that you have to change `[org 0x7e00]` to `[org 0x8000]`.

> ... and link stage1 and stage2 to work together?

That's not as easy as you think:

The BIOS will load one sector (510 bytes plus 2 bytes `0xAA55`) into the memory at 0x7C00. Using a normal BIOS there is **no possibility** to load more data!

The code in these 510 bytes ("stage 1") has to load the "state 2" into the memory: It may use functions `ah=2` or `ah=0x42` of `int 0x13` to do so.

If you have your own floppy format, this is quite simple:

You store "stage 2" in the second sector of the floppy disk and load the second sector.

If you want to load "stage 2" from a file system (e.g. from a file from a FAT-formatted disk), this is more tricky.

Comment: Its OK, But how will i do this  for example make.sh

Comment: *Unfortunately, I don't use "masm" but other assemblers* - Neither does the OP, this is a NASM question.

Comment: @PeterCordes It seems like this was a typo of mine. I should have written "**n**asm". I corrected that typo. I wanted to say that the assembler typically used by me does not know the `org` keyword at all.