# MOV DS, EAX segfaults?

Tags: assembly, gdb, x86-64, memory-segmentation

When I run `mov ds,rax`, it will throw error `Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault`

What's wrong with the assembly code?

```
global main

main:
    mov rax,0ffffH
    mov ds,rax
    mov rbx,6
    ret
```

[image: See screen shot]

Comment: Please don't post images of text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mov` to a segment register loads the internal segment base/limit / permissions stuff from [the GDT (Global Descriptor Table)](https://wiki.osdev.org/Global_Descriptor_Table).  (The base and limit are treated as 0 / -1 respectively in 64-bit mode, but `mov` to a segment register still has a real effect and still checks stuff.  You can't just expect arbitrary values to not cause problems.)

According to [Intel's manual for `mov`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mov), `mov Sreg, r/m` faults with `#GP(selector)` if the "segment selector index" (index into the GDT or LDT) "is outside the descriptor table limits".

**Linux delivers SIGSEGV if user-space causes an invalid page fault, or any kind of `#GP` exception.**

Since bit 2 is set (`1<<2`), this is indexing into the LDT (Local Descriptor Table), not GDT.  There probably isn't an LDT at all for your process if you didn't ask your OS (Linux?) to create one, e.g. with a `modify_ldt()` system call.

If you cleared that bit (`mov eax, 0xfffb`), it still faults on my Linux desktop.  From that we can infer that Linux didn't configure a GDT that large.  There's no reason to expect it would; it only needs a handful of segment descriptors for normal operation.  e.g. if you use `info reg`, you can see the segment register values are:

```
cs             0x33                51
ss             0x2b                43
ds             0x0                 0
es             0x0                 0
fs             0x0                 0
gs             0x0                 0
```

(`0` works as a "null selector" that has a special meaning of keeping x86-64's minimal remnants of segmentation happy; it's not actually descriptor privilege level 0 (a kernel-only data segment) even though the low 2 bits are `00`.  The low bits of `cs` are the expected `11` (ring 3 = user-space).)

Other possible reasons for exceptions include: "*If the DS, ES, FS, or GS register is being loaded and the segment pointed to is not a data or readable code segment.*"

---

I'm assuming you don't actually know much about segmentation, and I'm not trying to explain how to actually use segment registers.  The point I'm trying to make is that **you can't just use `ds` as 16 bits of scratch space for arbitrary integer data.**

If you want to know in more detail exactly what you can and can't put in `ds`, read Intel's manuals.  And the kernel source to see how it configures its GDT and LDT, or make a `modify_ldt()` system call.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Thanks, fixed.  I was lazy about checking that because it didn't affect the overall point of the answer (`ds` isn't scratch space), but glad to have it corrected.

Comment: Related: [Should using MOV instruction to set SS to 0x0000 cause fault #GP(0) in 64-bit mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57436125) - Intel's pseudo-code only covers protected mode, not 64-bit mode.  Kernel mode can use SS=0 but user-space still gets #GP(0).