# When I pass argument in function, she didn't launch in c low-level

Tags: c, assembly

I am creating an opeating ystem, and for my bootloader I need to call function with argument, my function without argument work but when I add argument the program totaly bug, it don't launch I don't understand why. The last question is [Can't launch function in c in low-level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66177561/cant-launch-function-in-c-in-low-level). It's the same problem but not the good explaination.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57931806/cannot-call-real-mode-c-function-from-bootloader-nasm-gcc-toolchain/57932741#57932741) might be of help.

Comment: Yeah it is that thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

If you had the same problem, just add `-Os -mregparm=3 -fomit-frame-pointer` in the option of the compiler. This could help you.