# How do I properly set up a linker script with a boot loader?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, ld, bootloader

I have a 2 stage bootloader and a c kernel function. I am trying to do this without using an initial file system.

The problem is that it's not making it to the second stage for entry and also not making it to the c function or the kernel. I put a char test in both the first and second stage, in order to test it by output, but its not printing the second stage char.

This lets me know there is an issue with the jmp from the first to the second stage because its not even making it to the first label in the second stage. There is also a print test in the c kernel function named _core and its not printing output either. Which of course it would not work, because control is lost before the first label in the second stage, so there's no reason to believe it would make it to the kernel call which is after.

The first stage is a regular .bin file and since I used the extern directive, the second stage, is an .o file. I separated them like its suppose to but I am not sure how everything is suppose to connect.

I mean the osboot.asm is getting assembled alone so there doesn't seem to be a connection to the linker, even doe I have a jmp problem, with no address to jmp to. Then how does the linker work, with the second stage .o file and the c file .o together, in order to call the kernel? What is the proper way of handling this?

I am assume the linker should be providing all the addresses needed.

**osboot.asm - first stage**

```
[BITS 16]
org 0x7C00

osboot:
     mov ah, 0x0e        ; BIOS teletype function
     mov al, 'B'         ; Character to print
     int 0x10            ; Call BIOS interrupt

     call read_osload

     jmp 0:0x7e00

%include "read_osload.inc"

times 510-($-$$) db 0       ; Limit the sector to 510 bytes
dw 0xAA55                   ; Boot signature and last 2 bytes of the first sector
```

**osload.asm - second stage**

```
[BITS 16]
section .osload
global _start

_start: jmp switch_pmode

%include "gdt.inc"

switch_pmode:
    mov ah, 0x0e        ; BIOS teletype function
    mov al, 'L'         ; Character to print
    int 0x10            ; Call BIOS interrupt

    cli
    lgdt [gdt_descriptor]

    mov eax, cr0
    or eax, 1
    mov cr0, eax

    jmp code_seg:p_mode

[BITS 32]
p_mode:
    mov ax, cs
    mov ds, ax
    mov ss, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax

    mov ebp, 0x90000
    mov esp, ebp

    [EXTERN _core]
    call _core
    hlt
```

**core.c - kernel**

```
void _core() 
{
    char* video_memory = (char*)0xb8000;

    video_memory[0] = 'E';
    video_memory[1] = 'L';
    video_memory[2] = 'L';
    video_memory[3] = 'E';

    video_memory[4] = 'O';
    video_memory[5] = 'S';
}
```

**read_osload.inc**

```
[BITS 16]

read_osload:
    mov ah, 0        ; reset the drive function
    mov dl, 0        ; drive 0 is the floppy drive
    int 0x13          ; call the BIOS interrupt to reset drive

    mov ax, 0x7E00   ; read address 0x7E00 so we can jmp to the second stage
    mov es, ax
    xor bx, bx

    mov ah, 0x02     ; read sector function
    mov al, 1        ; read 1 sector
    mov ch, 0        ; 0 = track 1  (18 sectors per track) no need to move from track 0
    mov cl, 2        ; read sector 2
    mov dh, 0        ; head number
    mov dl, 0        ; drive number. drive 0 is the floppy drive
    int 0x13          ; call the BIOS interrupt to read drive
    ret
```

**gdt.inc**

```
; null segment descriptor
gdt_start:
    dq 0x0

; code segment descriptor
gdt_code:
    dw 0xffff    ; segment length, bits 0-15
    dw 0x0       ; segment base, bits 0-15
    db 0x0       ; segment base, bits 16-23
    db 10011010b ; flags (8 bits)
    db 11001111b ; flags (4 bits) + segment length, bits 16-19
    db 0x08       ; segment base, bits 24-31

; data segment descriptor
gdt_data:
    dw 0xffff    ; segment length, bits 0-15
    dw 0x0       ; segment base, bits 0-15
    db 0x0       ; segment base, bits 16-23
    db 10010010b ; flags (8 bits)
    db 11001111b ; flags (4 bits) + segment length, bits 16-19
    db 0x10       ; segment base, bits 24-31

gdt_end:

; GDT descriptor
gdt_descriptor:
    dw gdt_end - gdt_start - 1 ; size (16 bit)
    dd gdt_start ; address (32 bit)

code_seg equ gdt_code - gdt_start
data_seg equ gdt_data - gdt_start
```

**link.ld**

```
ENTRY(_core)
OUTPUT_FORMAT("binary")
OUTPUT(core.bin)

SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x7C00;                  /* osboot.asm starts at 0x7C00*/
    .osboot : AT(0x7C00)
    {
        *(.text)
        *(.rodata)
        *(.data)
        _bss_start = .;
        *(.bss)
        *(COMMON)
        _bss_end = .;
    }

    . = 0x7E00;                 /* osload.asm starts at 0x7E00? we need a place to jmp to from osboot */
    .osload : AT(0x7E00)
    {
        *(.text)
        *(.rodata)
        *(.data)
        _bss_start = .;
        *(.bss)
        *(COMMON)
        _bss_end = .;
    }

    . = 0x1000;                /* core.c starts at 0x1000? we need a place to call kernel _core */
    ._core : AT(0x1000)
    {
        *(.text)
        *(.rodata)
        *(.data)
        _bss_start = .;
        *(.bss)
        *(COMMON)
        _bss_end = .;
    }

    kernel_sectors = (SIZEOF(._core) + 511) / 512;

    . = ALIGN(4); /* Ensure alignment between sections */

    /DISCARD/ : {
        *(.eh_frame)
    }
}
```

**makefile**

```
all: elle.flp

osboot.bin: osboot.asm
    nasm -f bin osboot.asm -o osboot.bin

osload.o: osload.asm
    nasm osload.asm -f elf32 -o osload.o

core.o: core.c
    gcc -m32 -fno-pie -Wall -ffreestanding --no-builtin -c core.c -o core.o

core.bin: core.o osload.o
    ld -T link.ld -melf_i386 -o core.bin core.o osload.o 

elle.flp: osboot.bin core.bin
    cat osboot.bin core.bin > elle.flp

clean:
    rm -f osboot.bin osload.o core.o load_core.o core.bin elle.flp
```

I have tried altering the link.ld in many different ways.
I have tried altering the make file in many ways.
I've tried compiling the osload.o and core.o, separately then combining them into a .bin, before linking them.
I've tried compiling the osload.o and core.o separately then linking them separately.

Comment: For starters, `jmp 0x7E00:0x0000` is already wrong. The linker script sets `. = 0x7e00` which means you need `jmp 0:0x7e00`. Furthermore, you specify `.text section starts at 0x8000` so that should actually be a `jmp 0:0x8000`. You should put the `osload` stuff into a separate section because as it is, you can't even be sure it will be at the start of `.text` and thus might not be at `0x8000` either.

Comment: Rule of thumb: if you have a linker script, do not use the `org` directive.  It's the linker's job to relocate the section to an origin, not the assembler's.

Comment: @fuz, sure, but that particular file is not linked.

Comment: @jester What do you mean?    /* .text section starts at 0:0x8000 */ is a comment there is no actual jmp for it. I was trying to figure how to do this. That's why I was asking. I rewritten it so many times it was a leftover comment.

Comment: As the comment says, the `.text` will be at `0x8000` so the `jmp 0x7e00:0x0000` is wrong, but that's also assuming your `osload` stuff ends up at the beginning of `.text` which is not guaranteed.

Comment: @jester I changed the `jmp 0x7E00:0x0000` to `jmp 0:0x7e00` but the linker I am not sure of. I have tried every way possible to understand it so that's why I posted the question. I appreciate the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to arrange the code using the linker script and have it place the boot signature in the appropriate place. The following linker script with some cleaned up code to fix a variety of bugs is below and assumes the kernel is loaded starting at physical address 0x8000. There were also issues with:

- Your GDT has incorrect values for the segment bases (bits 24-31).
- You only read one sector so none of the kernel is loaded
- You read the sectors from the disk into the wrong memory address in *ES:BX*.
- You didn't properly set up the segment registers at the beginning of your bootloader.
- You used the code selector in protected mode to initialize data segments.
- The drive number that was booted from is passed in register *DL* so you can use that instead of using drive 0 when doing disk accesses.

`link.ld`:

```
ENTRY(_core)
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf32-i386)

SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x7C00;                  /* osboot.asm starts at 0x7C00*/
    .osboot : AT(0x7C00) SUBALIGN(4)
    {
        osboot.o(.text)
        osboot.o(.*)
    }

    . = 0x7DFE;
    .bootsig : {
        SHORT(0xaa55);
    }

    . = 0x7E00;                 /* osload.asm starts at 0x7E00? we need a place to jmp to from osboot */
    .osload : AT(0x7E00) SUBALIGN(4)
    {
        osload.o(.text)
        osload.o(.*)
    }

    . = 0x8000;                /* core.c starts at 0x1000? we need a place to call kernel _core */
    ._core : SUBALIGN(4)
    {
        *(.text*)
        *(.rodata*)
        *(.data*)
    }

    .bss : SUBALIGN(4) {
        __bss_start = .;
        *(COMMON);
        *(.bss*);
    }
    . = ALIGN(4);              /* Round BSS up to 4 byte boundary */
    __bss_end = .;

    kernel_sectors = (SIZEOF(._core) + 511) / 512;

    /DISCARD/ : {
        *(.eh_frame)
        *(.comment)
    }
}
```

`gdt.inc`:

```
; null segment descriptor
gdt_start:
    dq 0x0

; code segment descriptor
gdt_code:
    dw 0xffff    ; segment length, bits 0-15
    dw 0x0       ; segment base, bits 0-15
    db 0x0       ; segment base, bits 16-23
    db 10011010b ; flags (8 bits)
    db 11001111b ; flags (4 bits) + segment length, bits 16-19
    db 0x00      ; segment base, bits 24-31

; data segment descriptor
gdt_data:
    dw 0xffff    ; segment length, bits 0-15
    dw 0x0       ; segment base, bits 0-15
    db 0x0       ; segment base, bits 16-23
    db 10010010b ; flags (8 bits)
    db 11001111b ; flags (4 bits) + segment length, bits 16-19
    db 0x00       ; segment base, bits 24-31

gdt_end:

; GDT descriptor
gdt_descriptor:
    dw gdt_end - gdt_start - 1 ; size (16 bit)
    dd gdt_start ; address (32 bit)

code_seg equ gdt_code - gdt_start
data_seg equ gdt_data - gdt_start
```

`read_osload.inc`:

```
[BITS 16]

read_osload:
    mov ah, 0        ; reset the drive function
;    mov dl, 0        ; drive in DL passed by the BIOS is the boot drive
    int 0x13          ; call the BIOS interrupt to reset drive

    xor ax, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov bx, 0x7E00   ; read address 0x7E00 so we can jmp to the second stage

    mov ah, 0x02     ; read sector function
    mov al, 15       ; read 15 sectors - this will need to be redone when the
                     ;     kernel gets larger
    mov ch, 0        ; 0 = track 1  (18 sectors per track) no need to move from track 0
    mov cl, 2        ; read sector 2
    mov dh, 0        ; head number
;    mov dl, 0        ; drive in DL passed by the BIOS is the boot drive
    int 0x13          ; call the BIOS interrupt to read drive
    ret
```

`osboot.asm`:

```
[BITS 16]
extern stage2

osboot:
     xor ax, ax          ; Initialize seg regsisters to 0 since
                         ; linker script will be placing bootloader at
                         ; org 0x7c00
     mov ds, ax
     mov es, ax
     mov ss, ax
     mov sp, 0x7c00      ; Place stack just below bootloader
                         ; at 0x0000:0x7c00

     mov ah, 0x0e        ; BIOS teletype function
     mov al, 'B'         ; Character to print
     int 0x10            ; Call BIOS interrupt

     call read_osload

     jmp 0:stage2

%include "read_osload.inc"
```

`osload.asm`:

```
[BITS 16]
global stage2

stage2: jmp switch_pmode

%include "gdt.inc"

switch_pmode:
    mov ah, 0x0e        ; BIOS teletype function
    mov al, 'L'         ; Character to print
    int 0x10            ; Call BIOS interrupt

    cli
    lgdt [gdt_descriptor]

    mov eax, cr0
    or eax, 1
    mov cr0, eax
    jmp code_seg:p_mode

[BITS 32]
p_mode:
    mov ax, data_seg
    mov ds, ax
    mov ss, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax

    mov ebp, 0x90000
    mov esp, ebp

    [EXTERN _core]
    call _core
    hlt
```

`core.c`:

```
void _core()
{
    volatile char* video_memory = (volatile char*)0xb8000;

    video_memory[0] = 'E';
    video_memory[2] = 'L';
    video_memory[4] = 'L';
    video_memory[6] = 'E';

    video_memory[8] = 'O';
    video_memory[10] = 'S';
}
```

`Makefile`:

```
all: elle.flp

osboot.o: osboot.asm
        nasm -f elf32 osboot.asm -o osboot.o

osload.o: osload.asm
        nasm osload.asm -f elf32 -o osload.o

core.o: core.c
        gcc -m32 -fno-pie -Wall -ffreestanding --no-builtin -c core.c -o core.o

core.bin: core.o osload.o osboot.o
        ld -T link.ld -melf_i386 -o core.elf core.o osload.o osboot.o
        objcopy -O binary core.elf core.bin

elle.flp: core.bin
        dd if=/dev/zero of=elle.flp bs=1K count=1440
        dd if=core.bin of=elle.flp conv=notrunc

clean:
        rm -f osboot.o osload.o core.o load_core.o core.bin elle.flp core.elf
```

---

### Notes

- As your kernel grows in size, you will eventually have to use a more appropriate method of reading a larger number of sectors into memory. I have some example code that reads floppy media using logical block addressing in this [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54894586/3857942).
- I have general bootloader tips and answers to a variety of boot related problems in this [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32705076/3857942).

Comment: I didn't realize you could make the first stage an .o file. If I would have known that, lmao, that external problem would have been an easier issue to understand.  I was trying to put the osboot.o in the ld earlier myself and was looking at `https://mcyoung.xyz/2021/06/01/linker-script/` so I understand the link.ld you provided alot better then the way I had it. It still isn't making it to the kernel? In bochs its shows its made it to the hlt.

Comment: @raven_lee: Did you take the exact code I have here without modifications and see if it works? It works in both BOCHs and QEMU here.

Comment: Yes, I took the code from here to make sure everything was correct. In wsl ubuntu everything compiles well, in bochs screen its only showing the letter B and L but no ELLE OS from the c function unless that needs to be redone, and in bochs output.txt it shows: 00014693531i[BIOS  ] Booting from 0000:7c00
00015362428i[CPU0  ] WARNING: HLT instruction with IF=0!

Comment: When making the first stage an .o file we don't have to use times and the signature?? or the link.ld is handling that also cause I see it defined in link.ld. If so thats nice!!

Comment: Take a close look at the first line of output in BOCHS when you run. In the very top left hand corner it should have printed characters ontop of the BIOS bootup text.

Comment: By using a linker script there is no ORG 0x7c00 in osboot.asm as that is handled by the linker script. My linker script places the 0xaa55 boot signature in the right place (at locations 0x7dfe) which are the last 2 bytes before 0x7e00. Because the linker script handles it none of that padding with TIMES has to be done in the osboot.asm file.

Comment: You are right its in the upper left like it should be!! I need to make a function to clear the screen. I expected it to be at the bottom lmao.