# Why does my assembly program gets stuck when it's excuting 'int 13h'?

Tags: assembly, operating-system, nasm, x86-16, bios

I'm trying to make an operating system and I've written two programs: boot.asm and loader.asm, the compilation process was very success, but when I'm using bochs to debug my program, it gets stuck at the command 'int 13h'.Did anyone has a solution to this problem?

Here's my code:

boot.asm:

```
org 07c00h

...
BPB_SecPerTrk dw 18
BS_DrvNum db 0
...

ReadOneSector:
    push bp
    mov sp, sp
    sub esp, 2
    mov byte [bp-2], cl
    push bx
    mov bl, [BPB_SecPerTrk]
    div bl
    inc ah
    mov cl, ah
    mov dh, al
    shr al, 1
    mov ch, al
    and dh, 1
    pop bx
    mov dl, [BS_DrvNum]
Label_Go_Reading:
    mov ah, 2
    mov al, byte [bp-2]
    int 13h ; the program gets stuck when running this line
    jc Label_Go_Reading
    add esp, 2
    pop bp
    ret
...

times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

Here's the debugger's output:

```
<bochs:45> n
Next at t=14041939
(0) [0x000000007ca1] 0000:7ca1 (unk. ctxt): mov al, byte ptr ss:[bp-2] ; 8a46fe
<bochs:46> n
Next at t=14041940
(0) [0x000000007ca4] 0000:7ca4 (unk. ctxt): int 0x13                  ; cd13
<bochs:47> n ;the program gets stuck when executing this line
```

Can anyone tell me why does the program gets stuck and how to solve this problem(I think maybe the code before can't let 'int 13h' run)

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the following line and don't use `n`. See if that helps. PS: why are you using `esp` in your code?

Comment: To clarify, does it get stuck the first time int 13h is called, or a second time? You may need to move `mov dl, [BS_DrvNum]` inside the loop as there may be BIOS implementations that do not preserve `dl` between calls. Also, you don't show how you're saving `BS_DrvNum` so make sure that has a valid value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> ReadOneSector:
>     push bp
>     mov sp, sp     <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
>     sub esp, 2
>     mov byte [bp-2], cl
> ```

There's a typo in the third line. You want to load the `BP` register, not just nop on `SP`!

Next solution avoids putting a local variable on the stack:

```
; IN (ax,es:bx,cl)
ReadOneSector:
    push  bp
    mov   ch, 2     ; CH Function number
    mov   bp, cx    ; CL Sector count
    push  bx
    mov   bl, [BPB_SecPerTrk]
    div   bl
    inc   ah
    mov   cl, ah
    mov   dh, al
    shr   al, 1
    mov   ch, al
    and   dh, 1
    pop   bx
    mov   dl, [BS_DrvNum]
Label_Go_Reading:
    mov   ax, bp    ; -> AH function number, AL sector count
    int   13h
    jc    Label_Go_Reading
    pop   bp
    ret
```

If this routine is named "Read **One** Sector", then why is there even a parameter (in `CL`) for the number of sectors?
Anyway, for reading/writing several sectors it's probably best to read/write a single sector and repeat that in a loop (look up [multitrack problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58564895/problem-with-bios-int-13h-read-sectors-from-drive)):

```
; IN (ax,es:bx,cl)
ReadMultipleSectors:
    pusha
    movzx bp, cl    ; CL Sector count 1+
NextSector:
    push  ax        ; (1)
    push  bx        ; (2)
    mov   bl, [BPB_SecPerTrk]
    div   bl
    inc   ah
    mov   cl, ah
    mov   dh, al
    shr   al, 1
    mov   ch, al
    and   dh, 1
    pop   bx        ; (2)
    mov   dl, [BS_DrvNum]
Label_Go_Reading:
    mov  ax, 0201h
    int  13h
    jc   Label_Go_Reading
    pop  ax         ; (1)
    inc  ax         ; Next sector number
    add  bx, 512    ; Next sector buffer
    dec  bp
    jnz  NextSector
    popa
    ret
```